# AutoAnimate FormKIt Documentation Issue - React

Tags: reactjs

I really love the way autoAnimate with formkit does this component on their website.
https://gyazo.com/cf6f4dc4e714f217507c662b3a288ab3

However, I cant find the example code for their animated list per the above?
https://auto-animate.formkit.com/

Yes you can go to their github, however all the examples are in vue. Is there an example that exists for react? https://github.com/formkit/auto-animate/blob/master/docs/src/examples/dropdown/dropdown.jsx

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I was able to find regarding react is this example:

https://auto-animate.formkit.com/#usage-react